# React: default proprerty of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm going through a React course, and today I met an issue.

I import a component dynamically. I don't get what's the meaning of `default` in this snippet:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        importComponent()
            .then (cmp => {
                this.setState({component: cmp.default})
            })
    }
```

What is `cmp.default` about?

Comment: Maybe it's for accessing the default export

Comment: Can you please post the link from where you get that?